# Angular 6 Lazy Loading for the same path and different modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Recall the lazy loading example (app-routing-module):

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

So, for example, if the current path is www.mydomain.com/home, and I pressed on a costumers button (which redirects me to www.mydomain.com/customers/something), the CostumersModule will be loaded.
(I will call "/costumers" a subdirectory from now on).

Now let's say we have another module, say BooksModule, consists of 2 pages:

BooksFirstComponent //path = www.mydomain.com/bookone

BooksSecondComponent //path = www.mydomain.com/booktwo

(Note that these pages do not have subdirectories, so I'm not sure how to lazy load them)

Is it possible to load the BookModule only when one of its pages is being clicked?

I'm not sure if this will do the job:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './books/books.module#BooksModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Is a subdirectory is a must when we do lazy loading?

And if not, how can you do it without a subdirectory?

Comment: You can put both these components in a shared module and load the shared module based on path. Or you can just configure your routes to load the components (don't declare in separate module)

Comment: @SachinGupta I didn’t understand exactly how to do it, can you provide an example?

Comment: I think your sample is pretty good, you only have to declare standard routing of your sub-routes in your lazy-loaded module `Books`, and it should work as expected ?
You can check whether the lazy-loaded module is called again or not in the browser debug tools.

I don't understand your question about sub-directories though. Is it because you have no directory to store your components in your module ? This should not be a problem at all.

Comment: logically you could add `'books'` as your path & then handle further route actions in your `BooksRoutingModule`

Comment: @AlexBeugnet For SEO reasons I don’t want some pages path to be in a subdirectory, but I do want them to load in lazy mode